# How to export SSRS charts to PDF at high resolution?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a simple SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services report with a bar chart. When I print directly from the preview window in Visual Studio everything looks good, but if I export the report to a PDF file and print it then the labels and even some of the vertical lines come out pixelated. How can I increase the resolution of the PDF export?

EDIT:

Setting `HumanReadablePDF=True` makes the PDF much larger (4 mb vs. 20 kb), but the chart still looks the same.

I can print directly from the preview window to a PDF file (using PrimoPDF) and the chart looks good -- maybe there's a way to do that instead of using the SSRS export function?

Answer (score 4):

Try messing with the device information settings, in particular the HumanReadiblePdf attribute. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154682.aspx
IIRC the setting is actually the opposite of what the documentation hints at compression wise.

Also take a look here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/donovans/pages/reporting-services-pdf-renderer-faq.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is still an issue in **SSRS 2008 R2**. The fix was to change my images from **PNG** to **JPEG**.  **@DanielAuger** was heading in the right direction with his last link.  I've included it again here with its title:

### [Reporting Services: PDF Renderer FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/donovans/archive/2007/07/20/reporting-services-pdf-renderer-faq.aspx)

---

My answer was found in the following excerpt at the bottom of the aforementioned link:

> ### I'm not using the controls in local mode and my PDFs are still big.  Why?
>
> **If your PDF contains charts or PNG images**, those images may be translated into bitmaps before being added to the PDF file.  Although this bitmap data will be recompressed, it will not be as space efficient as the original image.  To avoid this translation, **use JPEG images** or PNG files of color type 3 (PNG color type information can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG).
>
> Prior to Reporting Services 2005 SP1, PNG images of additional color types were allowed.  Unfortunately, in order to fix a **bug causing some PNGs to appear corrupted when rendered to PDF** we needed to add the color type restriction.  Even more unfortunate is the fact that charts are sent to the PDF renderer as non-color type 3 PNGs of high DPI.  This is certainly a limitation we want to remove in the future but very unlikely it will be fixed in Reporting Services 2005.
> *.
>
> <sub>***Note: emphasis mine.***</sub>